# Best way to share data between multiple views in Swift when not segueing directly

Tags: swift, segue

I am very new to programming and Swift. I am currently attempting to build an app where a user first logs in and then is segued to a split view with a menu in the master view to select different detail views. I would like one of these detailed views to display information on the user who has logged in on the first page.

I have successfully gotten my log in to display a users name, picture ect. on the first page. However I have not figured out the best way to transition this data to my detailed view.

Through research it seems like pushing the data with prepareForSegue is an option. However I run into an error that I can not cast my MasterViewController as a SplitViewController.

I have seen that you can push data through protocols and delegation between views and I believe there is a solution using coreData to create a database I could then reference.

I'm just teaching myself to code and trying to learn one new thing at a time as I need them. I'm just not sure which one to be trying to learn in this case.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you want to persist the user to reference in the future. You likely want to write a singleton model class (e.g. CurrentUserController) so that you can access the properties of the person who's logged in wherever you want. Passing that back and forth between controllers to persist it is likely going to be very fragile. If you already store the user somewhere accessible and you just want things to update, you can post a notification when someone logs in or out.

Answer (score 0):

Your MasterViewController and SplitViewControllers should be different classes. Check out the Master-Detail Application template, especially the split view code in the AppDelegate and storyboard layout to figure out how to wire this up. There's a segue from the SVC to both the MVC and the DVC, *plus*  a segue from the MVC *to* the DVC.